A set constructed using the Axiom of Choice，Construction of non-measurable sets
\begin{gather}
G = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x = r + n \sqrt{2} \text{ for some } r \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ and } n \in \mathbb{Z} \} \\
G_0 = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x = r + 2n \sqrt{2} \text{ for some } r \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ and } n \in \mathbb{Z} \} \\
G_1 = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x = r + (2n+1) \sqrt{2} \text{ for some } r \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ and } n \in \mathbb{Z} \}
\end{gather}
Define the equivalence relation $ \sim $ as follows: $ x \sim y $ if and only if $x - y$ belongs to $G_0 $. Using the Axiom of Choice, select one representative from each equivalence class to form a set $ E.$ Let $A＝E+G_0 $, I want to know  why $Aᶜ＝E+G_1？$
My confusion:
$E$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$,
$ G_0 $and $G_1 $ seem to be selecting points in $\mathbb{R}$ in a scattered manner. Can the union of $E+G_0$ and $E+ G_1$ represent all the points in $\mathbb{R}$,  Can someone help explain it?"

Do you want your equivalence relation be "difference in $G_0$" or "difference in $G$"? With the former, you already have $E + G_0 = \mathbb R$.

Assuming that $\sim$ is to be understood as an equivalence relation on $\mathbb R$, we have (unless I've overlooked something) $E+G_0=\mathbb R=E+G_1$. So what you want to prove is false.

@mihaild My mistake , the equivalence relation should be "difference in G" Would you mind give me more details？Thank you

@AndreasBlass  x~ y iff x-y belongs to G, sorry, my mistake ,could you show me the details ？

@user1374610 In the original version of the question, with $G_0$, consider an arbitrary $x\in\mathbb R$. By definition of $E$, there is some $y\in E$ such that $x-y\in G_0$. Then $x=y+(x-y)\in E+G_0$.

@AndreasBlass Thank you
